# Working with Neo4j Rest API in Swift

Tags: swift, rest, neo4j, httprequest, httpresponse

i am quite new to iOS and Swift and now i want to use Neo4j, a Graph Database for persistent saving of my data. 
I know there's a Lib named Theo for connecting to the Graph Database, but i want to use the REST API. Now i am not sure how to handle the HTTP-Request in order to get data from Database to my iOS-App written in Swift?
Anyone has some helpful clues for my?

Thanks hannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Theo library](https://github.com/GraphStory/neo4j-ios) that you mention is a wrapper around the Neo4j REST API. The benefit of using such a library is that it takes care of things like JSON serialization, error handling, adding the correct headers to HTTP requests, etc.

You can use Cypher with the [transactional Cypher REST API endpoint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html) using Swift like this (**Note**: this uses the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library for handling the HTTP request.):

```
import Alamofire

let cypherStatement = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Bob'})-[:LIKES]->(pizza:Food {type: 'Pizza'})<-[:LIKES]-(:Person {name: 'William'}) WITH pizza MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(pizz) RETURN p.name AS name"  
let endpoint = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"
let requestBody = [
        "statements": [
            [
                "statement": cypherStatement
            ]
        ]
    ]
Alamofire.request(.POST, endpoint, parameters: requestBody, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }
```

Which logs:

```
[Request]: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fafcb637320> { URL:     http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit }
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fafcb81d480> { URL: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit } { status code: 200, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Content-Length" = 91;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Fri, 18 Dec 2015 19:29:41 GMT";
Server = "Jetty(9.2.z-SNAPSHOT)";
} }
[Data]: 91 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    errors =     (
    );
    results =     (
                {
            columns =             (
                name
            );
            data =             (
                                {
                    row =                     (
                        Bob
                    );
                },
                            {
                    row =                     (
                        William
                    );
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

**Edit**

Making the same request without using Alamofire would look like this:

```
let cypherStatement = "CREATE (:Person {name: 'Bob'})-[:LIKES]->(pizza:Food {type: 'Pizza'})<-[:LIKES]-(:Person {name: 'William'}) WITH pizza MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIKES]->(pizz) RETURN p.name AS name"  
let endpoint = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit"
let requestBody = [
        "statements": [
            [
                "statement": cypherStatement
            ]
        ]
    ]

guard let url = NSURL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error")
            return true
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json",forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        do{
            let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestBody, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            request.HTTPBody = jsonData

            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                let result: NSDictionary
                do {
                    result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                        options: []) as! NSDictionary
                } catch  {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    return
                }
                print("\(result)")
            })
            task.resume()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("JSON serialization error")
            return true
        }
```

Comment: Thank you William Lyon,

i have seen your post today, and tried some days ago before you posted this solution the Alamofire Lib. Did not know how to push a cypher query to the request. Thank you very much!